# Custom Acivity property does not show Collection Editor in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I have written a custom CodeActivity for .net Workflow 4.0, and one of my (non inarg/outarg) properties is a collection, which I want to be able to populate in the designer, using the standard collection editor.

This is my property

```
public Collection<string> Columns
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

No matter what I do, (I have tried all the designer serializationvisibility options, Editor attribute specifying CollectionEditor etc etc), the Property Inspectory NEVER shows the collection editor 'ellipses button'...

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the PropertyGrid supports "Collection Editor" for generic collections.